# Permission denied in tmp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just deployed a Rails 3 app with Ruby 1.9.2. I have been getting several errors.

1. `application.css` wasn't compiled. so I set pre compilation in `production.rb` to false;
2. Then I got: `cannot generate tempfile`, so I did `rake tmp:clear`;
3. And now I get `ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /srv/www/appname/tmp/cache/assets):` and I haven't been able to fix this one.

Please help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If the `user:group` running your web server is `http:http` and it's running on *nix, do this:

```
sudo chown -R http:http /srv/www/appname/
```

Also, silly question, but does /tmp/cache/assets exist?

And, if so, as [@leonel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912895/leonel) points out, you may also need to change the permissions:

```
chmod 777 /srv/www/appname/tmp/cache
```

Be careful setting `777` permissions on anything. Only do this to verify a permissions issue, then reset to the most minimal permissions necessary.

Comment: So that command would give ownership to anybody? I had to change the permissions of cache to drwxrwxrwx.

Comment: @leonel gave the right answer: `chmod 777 /srv/www/appname/tmp/cache` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Please be careful when giving any directory 777 permissions: See [Fixing answers that recommend “chmod 777”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885/4174897).

Answer (score 8):

Most likely you're running your app under apache passenger.

You have to change the owner of config/environment.rb to somebody who has permissions to your app's folder.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/app
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Make the tmp folder of your project writable:

   ```
   chown -R group:user /path/to/rails/app/tmp
   chmod -R 777 /path/to/rails/app/tmp
   ```
2. In your console, run `rake tmp:cache:clear`
3. Restart your application.

Comment: **STOP**. Don't do this! This is potentially very dangerous. Please see [Fixing answers that recommend “chmod 777”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885/4174897).

Comment: rake tmp:cache:clear solves the problem!  only this!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Now for those of us that are using windows
- If you are an administrator and see this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ utime_failed) C:/User/..../tmp/cache/assets/sprochets/v3.0/E5/E5PZx-mq8.cache
```

Then it is Permission and Ownership setting issue on Windows.
You can go to the tmp folder on your application and give yourself(User) permission to **Read, Write and Execute ** on the folder.
Click [here][1] to view how to give permissions.

Quick Fix. Open your terminal and run the following command as an administrator

```
    takeown /f <location of your app tmp folder> /r /d y
```

Then Restart your server.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't create your Rails application with the user running the server now. Can you paste the output of `ls -alh /srv/www/appname/tmp/cache/assets` and tell us the user running the webserver ?

Comment: No. I created the app in my development machine and then uploaded it to the production machine using FTP. I think the user running the server is root. I made it work already but I had to change the permissions on the cache folder to `drwxrwxrwx`. If there is a better way please let me know. This is the output of the ls- alh command: http://pastebin.com/v1sH5Qhb

Comment: Users not in the nogroup group can't write to your folder. You need to change the owner/group of the tmp folder.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error recently. Apache was not able to write to tmp directory

> cannot generate tempfile
>   `/tmp/RackRewindableInput2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>       /app-lib/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:52:in`initialize'
>       app-dir/vendor/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/rewindable_input.rb:73:in `new'
>       app-dir/vendor/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/rewindable_input.rb:73:in`make_rewindable'
>       app-dir/vendor/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/rewindable_input.rb:26:in `read'
>       app-dir/vendor/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/request.rb:134:in`POST'

I checked permission of tmp directory and it had permission to all groups to write to it. 
I changed owner of tmp directory and it didn't resolve the error either.

The culprit was tmp directory was filled with too many large files, and looks like somehow apache didn't had enough space to write this new file. 
Cleared all temp and old files. It sorted out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We need to grant permissions to access the required directory for the system root user

```
sudo chmod 777 -R your_project_directory_to_be_access
```

In your case you can use:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /srv/www/appname/tmp/
```

For security reasons, just keep in your mind:

`chmod 777` gives everybody read, write and execute rights which for most problems is definitively too much.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution without giving everyone manage rights to tmp folder is like that:

```
 sudo rake tmp:cache:clear
```

This will clear the temp folder and when you run `rails server` again it won't give error.

Answer (score -1):

In my localhost it gave this error, and the command `chmod 777 C:/Sites/project_name/tmp/cache/` solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Most probably you gave permission to your app's main folder **read and execute mode**. However, in order to generate new files from your app, you also need to **give write permission for required folder**. For example: yUML uses tmp folder for generating files. I gave tmp folder write permission:

chmod -R 777 /usr/share/nginx/html/yuml_product/tmp

solved my problem.

Comment: **STOP**. Don't do this! This is potentially very dangerous. Please see [Fixing answers that recommend “chmod 777”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885/4174897).