# Permissions on /tmp/cache/assets on RAIL app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, assets, tmp

I have a permissions problem.
Using wickedpdf on my rails app to print, it produces tmp assets files into the dir `/tmp/cache/assets`.
The files that it writes, like this one `sprockets%2F2c9f9e326ac1c7cd3f07a1a3c9051874` have `owner="nobody"` and `permissions="rw--------"` so the asset wickedpdf gives an error while printing.

It's possible to correct this with a simple `chmod -R 777 /tmp` but i can't do this everytime the asset produces a new subdirectory into `/tmp` with no permissions.
It's possible to set tmp dir and its subdirectories and files with all permissions for ever, also for new files that my assets will produce in future?

Comment: Addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524262/permission-denied-in-tmp

Comment: Sorry but it's not the same problem. I need a different solution.

Comment: Are you running in apache or ngnix? Can you tell us the web server user, for example in apache is www-data, so one of the solution is assign permissions to this user in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can change permission for all the files and sub directories in temp/ directory,

like:
       chmod -R 777 /tmp/*

Answer (score 0):

There can be cache problems if you are using puma or rails very often.

I was facing same problem when switching from `> puma` to `> rails s` to start rails app.

Solution: You can delete cache for assets manually inside tmp/cache/ path