# Permission denied on sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here is error in my rails app, using nginx on production. How to solve this permissions issue?
`style.scss.css` file is in subfolder `voyage`, maybe this has some effect? - but `style.scss.erb` renamed to `style.css.erb` works well!

```
F, [2014-10-27T16:59:57.605973 #790] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /var/www/viewer/tmp/cache/assets/production/sass/f343497db8856b02b621e5e7a375554bcb8decb5
  (in /var/www/viewer/app/assets/stylesheets/voyage/style.scss.erb)):
    15:         %>
    16:         <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<%= url_for @logo.dynamic_attachment_url("64x64#") %>">
    17:   <% end %>
    18:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "voyage/style", media: "all" %>
    19:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "voyage/shadowbox", media: "all" %>
    20:   <%= javascript_include_tag "voyage/voyage" %>
    21:   <%= javascript_include_tag "voyage/shadowbox" %>
  app/views/layouts/voyage.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_voyage_html_erb__471689782555352934_45021440'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524262/permission-denied-in-tmp).

To quote user Adam Emberlin:

> If the user:group running your web server is http:http and it's
>   running on *nix, do this:
>
> sudo chown -R http:http /srv/www/appname/ Also, silly question, but
>   does /tmp/cache/assets exist?
>
> And, if so, as @leonel points out, you may also need to change the
>   permissions:
>
> chmod 777 /srv/www/appname/tmp/cache

You might what to Google for information on nginx user permissions.

Comment: yes, `/tmp/cache/assets` exist. But I noticed, that /tmp/cache/assets/production has 777 permissions, but /tmp/cache/assets/prooduction/sass/ has 755. Maybe this can be an issue?

Comment: what's the file permission read out of `style.sass.erb` look like? as in, `ls -l` of the file?

Comment: here it is `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10827 Oct 27 19:13 /var/www/viewer/app/assets/stylesheets/voyage/style.scss.erb`

Comment: There's the problem, it can't be executed by any one, the last one should be `r-x`. try `chmod -R 777 /var/www/`

Comment: there is permissions from other app scss in the same server, which works: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12447 Aug 18 18:56 /var/www/becomr/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss.erb` (but it is not in a subfolder)